# how to insert last_insert_id in sql query of csv query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

i am importing csv data into mysql database using codegniter framework. my database has two table promotion and promotion_product.promotion table is 3 fields name as promotion_id,name,start_dateand end_date.promotion_id is the primary key of promotion table.promotion_id is the auto incremment.promotion_product table is 5 fields id,promotion_id,sku,price,map.   promotion_id is the foreign key of this table. i am importing csv file this table.csv field is sku,price and map.i am not getting how to insert promotion_id of promotion_porduct table.i am using last_insert_id.my code is below:

my model is:

```
     public function save_csv($data,$data1) {

            $this->db->insert('promotion', $data1);
            $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            print_r($insert_id);
            $infile = $data['upload_data']['full_path'];
            //print_r($infile);

            $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $infile . "'
                            INTO TABLE promotion_product
                            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
                            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
                            IGNORE 1 LINES 
                            (promotion_id,sku, price, map)";
            print_r($sql);
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);

            //var_dump($query);

            return $query;
        }
```

Comment: try with `$this->db->insert_id()`

Comment: got the last_id but how to insert into csv load query

Comment: oh, sorry, didnt understood the question

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to do manually.
First insert into database then you will get last_insert_id and then read CSV file and create array of CSV and last_insert_id dump that array into a database.